# MySql insert after validation

Tags: php, try-catch

How can I add a MySQL insert if there are no errors caught?
Here's my code:

```
foreach($data as $key => $value){

    try{
        $rules[$key]->assert($value);
    } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
        $errors = $e->findMessages([
        'email' => 'Email must be a valid email address.',
        'equals' => 'Both passwords must match.']);
        echo $e->getFullMessage().'<br />';
    }

}
```

I've tried adding the code after the catch but that executes it several times because it's inside a loop.

Placing the code outside of the loop causes it to always execute.

Comment: Just write any other code that you would like php to execute subsequently if there are no errors after the catch block.

Comment: @Shadow I tried that however because it's inside a loop it executes multiple times.

Comment: Then place the code after the loop.

Answer (score -1):

If no errors were thrown, the code keeps being interpreted. So you should just add the code you want after the `catch`, like so:

```
foreach($data as $key => $value){

    try{
        $rules[$key]->assert($value);
    } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
        $errors = $e->findMessages([
        'email' => 'Email must be a valid email address.',
        'equals' => 'Both passwords must match.']);
        echo $e->getFullMessage().'<br />';
    }

    // your code here

}
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer but because it is inside a foreach the subsequent code gets executed the number of times a value was passed in this case 4 times. How to avoid that?

Comment: You can break the foreach using ```break``` - break ends execution of the current for, foreach, while, do-while or switch structure: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Comment: Even if there were errors resulting in a `InvalidArgumentException` this code will still be executed.

Comment: a vote down? seriously? this website is getting ridiculous.